# Magento remove diamond question mark

Tags: php, mysql, magento, character-encoding, undefined-symbol

I have a diamond question mark on my page which gets php code from the mysql database.

How do i get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SET NAMES uft8` as SQL query

And this 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`
on your html page

Depending on the charset that you are using.